# Why do I need another EPS power connector?

Tags: motherboard, power, compatibility, cable, eps

Why do I need another EPS power connector?

I own all the parts listed in the PC build I am referring to. My motherboard manual and power-supply manual all say that they only have one EPS/ATX8PIN power connector. PCPartPicker tells me that I need an additional EPS cable. I want to know what I need to do. My pc build is:

https://uk.pcpartpicker.com/user/Jakir/saved/rL3jcf

Comment: Edit: just noticed you already have all the parts - Build your system and see if it works? And if you prove they are wrong, there is a link to notify the site that their recommendation is incorrect. In regards to Why, the answer below maybe an answer, or you can ask the pc parts picker site to tell you what kind of algorithm they use to come up with that recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

You might an additional one for the liquid pump. Most motherboards do not come with cables.